# Grails always tries to uninstall plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Each time I'm runnin Grails app, it tries to uninstall an plugin (`resources-1.2.RC2`). When it installed using IntelliJ IDEA, it uninstall it sucessfully, I see:

```
| Uninstalled plugin [resources]
```

and fails with:

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: 
  srcdir "***/2.1.1/projects/***/plugins/resources-1.2.RC2/grails-app/resourceMappers" 
  does not exist! (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Notice, that I can install this plugin only by using InteliJ IDEA, when I'm trying to install it from command line (using `grails install-plugin resources`) it logs only:

```
| Plugin not installed.
```

If plugin isn't installed, and i'm doing `grails run-app`, it writes (each time!):

```
| Warning No plugin [resources-1.2.RC2] installed, cannot uninstall
```

app fails because cannot find required classes from `resources` plugin.

--

I guess it's happening because of corrupted config inside `~/grails` (I've tried to uninstall it some time ago), and it execute this action on each run. But I can find.

I even tried to remove project dir from `~/.grails/2.1.1/projects` - not helped.

How I can stop it from removing this plugin? Whre grails stores infomration what plugin it shoud uninstall?

PS Also, I can't understand, why `plugins { compile ":resources:1.2.RC2" }` in `BuildConfig.groovy` not used by grails? I always need to run `install-plugin` command to make it working?

Comment: Seems that it's bug http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9421

Answer (score 0):

Actually, install-plugin is deprecated. Use BuildConfig.groovy instead. To get everything set up properly, delete all plugins from your application.properties file. Then add them to your BuildConfig.groovy.
IntelliJ is not really good with catching these kind of updates, so you might have to run refresh-dependencies manually after updating your BuildConfig. That is properly why it didn't work before.